# Drupal 8 theming maintenance vs. update.php

Tags: drupal, drupal-8, theming

In Drupal 8 you are able to use a specific theme for viewing the site which is shown to users in maintenance mode.

The basics are:

> (1) uncomment the line

```
# $settings['maintenance_theme'] = 'bartik';
```

> in *settings.php* and set the theme you want to be used for maintenance
>
> (2) create a template *maintenance-page.html.twig* in your custom theme's template directory (*core/modules/system/templates/maintenance-page.html.twig* as a starter)

So this works great, but it also changes the theme used when running update.php with all its interactions.

Is there a way to use the custom theme for **only** the page dislayed to the user when the site is running in maintenance mode? Using the admin theme for update.php and stuff?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This module should solve your issue.
It allows you to set which theme is used for which parts of your website.

So you could set all /admin pages to use another theme.

https://www.drupal.org/project/themekey

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but this is not compatible with Drupal Core 8.